# Given a bijection $q: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, find $q(1000)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

We were given a bijection of $q: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ that spirals out from $(0,0)$.

[image: This is the only description of the function given.]

I need to find $q(1000)$. I noticed that the top left and bottom right corners of each "spiral" are squares of incrementing even and odd integers in $\mathbb{N}$. How would I go about getting the point $q(1000)$?

Edit: The original bijection is from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. The numbers on each point are incremented values from the previous point on the spiral, not coordinates.

Comment: This is the Ulam spiral.  You could look that up.  You are expected to count from the preceding square.

Comment: I looked at your diagram, and there are no negative numbers. $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of positive whole numbers. The double-struck letter $\mathbb{Z}$ symbolizes the set containing zero, positive whole numbers, and negative whole numbers. Did you mean a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$? Or is the original correct $(\mathbb{N} \implies \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon The point labelled with a natural number $N$ is the point that $N$ goes to in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: To refine your counting a bit, spot where the odd squares fall in the diagram.  Then work out which square contains the odd square closest to $1000$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the integer $(2N)^2$ gets mapped to the top left of the "spiral". Now just notice that this top left coordinate is always of the form $(-N,N)$. Since, $32^2 = 1024$ and $32 = 2(16)$, we have that $q(1024) = (-16,16)$. To find $q(1000)$, we move the point $(-16,16)$ to the right $24$ times (or in other words add $24$ to the $x$ coordinate) and get that $q(1000)= (8,16)$.

Also what you're noticing about the top left and bottom right corners can be viewed as a consequence of the formula

$$1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + ... + (2n - 1) = n^2 $$